# How to convert json into excel format using python

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to convert json file into excel but somehow panda is not able to do it for all the keys.

I have a json input:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "level": "L3_SW",
            "name": "L23",
            "type": "CM"
        },
        {
            "level": "L3_SW",
            "name": "SOFT",
            "type": "QM"
        }],
   "context": {
        "config": {
            "project_area_name": "XYZ",
            "component_name": "Configuration",
            "config_name": "_WorkOn",
            "bu": "H"
        },
        "meta": {
            "project": {
                "name": "_WorkOn",
                "key": "2023-05-02_96614cc50ac8dc7e121f7090",
                "started_at": "2023-05-02-16-00"
            },
            "task": {
                "started": "2023-05-02-16-00",
                "finished": "2023-05-02-16-00",
                "req_count": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is just one of a json file and I don't know what will be the structure of other json inputs.

I tried with panda library with I guess it required specific key which I don't want.

```
json_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Select a JSON file', filetypes=[('JSON files','*.json')])

    # Load the JSON file into a pandas dataframe
    data = json.load(open(json_file_path))
    print(data)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data["result"])  #=============> this giving me output of excel column only of result array.

    # Ask the user to select a location to save the Excel file
    excel_file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(title='Save as Excel',defaultextension='.xlsx')

    # Save the dataframe as an Excel file
    df.to_excel(excel_file_path, index=False)
```

How can I convert entire json to excel irrespective of the json structure which can give me all columns of the keys ?

Comment: you'd have to "flatten" your json first, which would lead to ambiguous keys...e.g. you have a "name" property in result[0] and also in context["meta"]["project"] how should this be handled?

Comment: @mrxra I am not sure of that since I cannot change the json input. Something like in project column , there will be 3 more column of name, key, started_at may be. I cannot say what will be the contents inside json input. Only thing is I need to create columns for all keys with values

Comment: what should the "title" row in your excel contain if you have multiple "name", "id", "whatever" fields in your unknown json structure? or you don't need named columns in excel?

Comment: how is your excel to look like _exactly_? e.g. 2 columns with keys from your json in column A and values in column B? or first row keys, second row values?

Comment: @mrxra No, the keys should be the title of each column. For example of my code I am able to generate result array with column name- level, name , type. Like the same way if I can generate more columns like project_area_name, component_name etc

Comment: ...you are aware that this will generate 1 excel file per json file with only 1 single data row?

Comment: @mrxra yes, I am aware that this need to generate 1 excel per json file. But cannot say about rows and columns. I just need to have all the datas in excel of the json keys having values.

Answer (score 0):

this will convert any json structure into a flat excel table, with the keys from your json in column A and the corresponding values in column B:

```
import json
import flatdict
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd

data = json.loads("""{
    "result":[{
        "level": "L3_SW",
        "name": "L23",
        "type": "CM"
    },{
        "level": "L3_SW",
        "name": "SOFT",
        "type": "QM"
    }],
    "context":{
        "config": {
            "project_area_name": "XYZ",
            "component_name": "Configuration",
            "config_name": "_WorkOn",
            "bu": "H"
        },
        "meta": {
            "project": {
                "name": "_WorkOn",
                "key": "2023-05-02_96614cc50ac8dc7e121f7090",
                "started_at": "2023-05-02-16-00"
            },
            "task": {
                "started": "2023-05-02-16-00",
                "finished": "2023-05-02-16-00",
                "req_count": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
""")

d = dict(flatdict.FlatterDict(data))
# EITHER: column A: keys, column B: values
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
df.to_excel("test.xlsx", header=False)

# OR: row 1: keys, row 2: values
# df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([d])
# df.to_excel("test.xlsx", index=False)
print(df)
```

output:

```
result:0:level                                                  L3_SW
result:0:name                                                     L23
result:0:type                                                      CM
result:1:level                                                  L3_SW
result:1:name                                                    SOFT
result:1:type                                                      QM
context:config:project_area_name                                  XYZ
context:config:component_name                           Configuration
context:config:config_name                                    _WorkOn
context:config:bu                                                   H
context:meta:project:name                                     _WorkOn
context:meta:project:key          2023-05-02_96614cc50ac8dc7e121f7090
context:meta:project:started_at                      2023-05-02-16-00
context:meta:task:started                            2023-05-02-16-00
context:meta:task:finished                           2023-05-02-16-00
context:meta:task:req_count                                         1
```

Comment: I am getting this - `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required` basically on this line : `d = dict(flatdict.FlatterDict(data))`

Comment: ...not with the example from the code above I assume? what does your json look like?

Comment: Same what I posted in the question. Code is `data = json.load(open(json_file_path))
    json_formatted_str = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
    d = dict(flatdict.FlatterDict(json_formatted_str))`

Comment: that's not possible. the data you posted has trailing "," chars which json.load() cannot handle. json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 7 column 9 (char 119)
==> run the code i posted, then adapt it to your needs. the data it contains is _your_ data, but fixed :)

Comment: as for the trailing comma issue in your json file, you probably have to fix them: "trailing commas are not allowed in JSON" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas)

Comment: How can I do in my case then? Choosing json file from file path system ?

Comment: your "json" is _not_ json. copy/paste it e.g. here https://jsonlint.com/ and it will tell you what's wrong: you have trailing commas that should not be there. fix it. then load the data as you just did `data = json.load(open(json_file_path))`

Comment: When I am checking this on jsonlint `json_formatted_str = json.dumps(data, indent=4)`. It is showing proper json validation. So not getting where the trailing commas is coming from

Comment: ...i have absolutely _no_ clue what you are doing with your data or where it comes from. but the data you provided in your post/question above is *not* valid json (copy it, paste it to jsonlint.com and it will tell you what's wrong). I don't know what you have in your files either. but if `json.load(open(json_file_path))` does *not* raise an exception, it should be just fine, otherwise you'll have to fix your data (where ever it comes from)

Comment: My bad in posting the json. Corrected now. But even my json is correct it is not working with filepath. Can you create a json file and select the same way I am doing and check.